# Truth tellers or liars among two people

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Two guys, number One and number Two. You ask number One "Is there a truth-teller among you?". He replies and you have the answer to your question. What is number One and what is number Two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> #1 is a liar and #2 is a truth teller

Reason:

> Assume that #1 and #2 are truth tellers, the answer to your question is Yes
>  Assume that #1 is a truth teller and #2 isn't, the answer to your question is Yes
>  Assume that #1 is a liar and #2 is a truth teller, the answer to your question is No
>  Assume that #1 and #2 are liars, the answer to your question is Yes
>  Since you are able to deduce who is who from this single question, the only combination where there is no uncertainty is if you get a No response.